# How can these two methods be refactored into one method

Tags: java, java-8, enums

Abstract as a method, using the lamda expression
How to merge
Convert an enumeration into a map in Java

```java
public Collection<Map<String, String>> getAllStoreTypeList() {
    Collection<ShopTypeEnum> shopTypeEnums = getAllStoreTypeEnus();
    List<Map<String, String>> result = shopTypeEnums.stream().map(e -> {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(VALUE, e.getValue());
        map.put(NAME, e.name());
        map.put(TAG_PROP_TYPE, TAG_TYPE);
        return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}


public Collection<Map<String, String>> getAllShopBussinessList() {
    Collection<ShopBusinessEnum> shopBusinessEnums = getShopBusinessEnus();
    List<Map<String, String>> result = shopBusinessEnums.stream().map(e -> {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(VALUE, e.getValue());
        map.put(NAME, e.name());
        map.put(TAG_PROP_TYPE, TAG_TYPE);
        return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```

The `ShopTypeEnum` and `ShopBusinessEnum` declarations

```java
public enum ShopBusinessEnum  implements EnumValueWare {

    beauty("美容"),
    maintenance("养护"),
    fix("维修"),
    paint("喷漆"),
    metalPlate("钣金"),
    certificate("办证"),
    violation("违章"),
    insurance("保险"),
    check("例检"),
    boutique("精品"),
    repair("抢修"),
    vehicleParts("全车件"),
    battery("电瓶"),
    tire("轮胎"),
    decoration("装潢"),
    conversion("改装");


    private static final Map<String, ShopBusinessEnum> LOOKUP = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    static {
        for (ShopBusinessEnum shopBusinessEnum : EnumSet.allOf(ShopBusinessEnum.class)) {
            LOOKUP.put(shopBusinessEnum.value, shopBusinessEnum);
        }
    }

    private String value;

    ShopBusinessEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static ShopBusinessEnum fromValue(String value) {
        return LOOKUP.get(value);
    }

    public static Map<String, ShopBusinessEnum> getLOOKUP() {
        return LOOKUP;
    }
}

public enum ShopTypeEnum implements EnumValueWare {

    _4s("4s店"),
    repairShop("维修厂"),
    chainStore("连锁店"),
    quickRepaired("快修快保店"),
    insurancePainting("钣金喷漆"),
    carBeauty("汽车美容"),
    onlyTire("轮胎专营"),
    onlyBattery("电瓶专营"),
    modifiedStore("改装店");

    private static final Map<String, ShopTypeEnum> LOOKUP = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    static {
        for (ShopTypeEnum shopTypeEnum : EnumSet.allOf(ShopTypeEnum.class)) {
            if (shopTypeEnum.ordinal() == 0) {
                shopTypeEnum.setValue(shopTypeEnum.value.replace("_", ""));
            }
            LOOKUP.put(shopTypeEnum.value, shopTypeEnum);
        }
    }

    private String value;

    ShopTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static ShopTypeEnum fromValue(String value) {
        return LOOKUP.get(value);
    }

    public static Map<String, ShopTypeEnum> getLOOKUP() {
        return LOOKUP;
    }
}

// common interface
public interface EnumValueWare {

    String getValue();

}
```

// call

```java
    public Collection<Map<String, String>> get(Supplier<Collection<? extends Enum<? extends EnumValueWare>>>  supplier) {
        return supplier.get().stream().map(e -> {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
            map.put(VALUE, e.getValue());// error can not resolve method getValue
            map.put(NAME, e.name());
            map.put(TAG_PROP_TYPE, TAG_TYPE);
            return map;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: pass the original list as parameter, the rest is shared code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Supplier<Collection<? extends Enum<?>>>` to obtain a collection to iterate over.

```
public Collection<Map<String, String>> get(Supplier<Collection<? extends Enum<?>>> supplier) {
    return supplier.get().stream().map(e -> {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      // populate
      return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To call it,

```
object.get(() -> getAllStoreTypeEnus());
object.get(() -> getShopBusinessEnus());
```

I have noticed that you are using `e.getValue()` which isn't a part of the `Enum` interface.

I am assuming there is a common interface

```
interface ValueAware {
     String getValue(); 
}

enum ShopTypeEnum implements ValueAware { ... }
enum ShopBusinessEnum implements ValueAware { ... }
```

so you could narrow the parameter type to

```
Supplier<Collection<? extends Enum<? extends ValueAware>>>
```

Otherwise, you would be getting a compilation error on

```
map.put(VALUE, e.getValue());
```

Comment: can not work 

`
return supplier.get().stream().map(e -> {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
            map.put(VALUE, e.getVale()); // error can not resolve method getValue
            map.put(NAME, e.name());
            map.put(TAG_PROP_TYPE, TAG_TYPE);
            return map;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
`

Comment: @cheng.pro are you using a `Supplier<Collection<? extends Enum<? extends ValueAware>>>`?

Comment: @cheng.pro and `getValue()` is a part of that interface?

Comment: @cheng.pro and, please, update the question with the `ShopTypeEnum` and `ShopBusinessEnum ` declarations

Comment: @cheng.pro your enums don't have a common interface. Please, read my answer carefully.

Comment: @cheng.pro I don't see it: `enum ShopTypeEnum  {` <-- there is no "implements"

Comment: @cheng.pro it should work, I tested it on my machine before posting. Update the question with how you called the method

Comment: @cheng.pro Care to elaborate? Your replies like "call the method" and "in another class" make little sense and don't shed light on the problem

Comment: e.getValue() // error: can not resolve method getValue

Comment: private Collection<Map<String, String>> getTags(Supplier<Collection<? extends EnumValueWare>> supplier)

will be OK.

Comment: @cheng.pro it means that not all the types you are passing are enums (since you can't do `? extends Enum<? extends ValueAware>`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would do to simply change:

```
Collection<ShopBusinessEnum> shopBusinessEnums = getShopBusinessEnus();
```

to:

```
Collection<? extends Enum> theEnums = ...
```

Because then you still deal with some sort of Enums, but you are independent of the actual type. Thus you should be able to nicely use one piece of code to iterate such a collection.

Like:

```
public Collection<Map<String, String>> getProperty(Collection<? extends Enum> theEnums) {
  return theEnums.stream().map(....
```